# Using an API of a website in a servlet . Is this the right way?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
public java.lang.StringBuffer getRequestURL()
```

I am using this method to call the API of another website which gives XML data as response to it . Is this the right method to be used with HTTPrequest/response. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make HTTP requests from within a Servlet you do it as you would from any process. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  URL url = new URL("http://www.targetdomain.com/api?key1=value1&key2=value2...");

  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);    // 5 seconds
  conn.setRequestMethod("GET");       
  conn.connect();
  BufferedReader rd  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

  String line;
  StringBuffer bf = new StringBuffer();
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      bf.append(line);
  }
  conn.disconnect(); 

  //... pass bf to an XML parser and do your processing...
}
```

Depending on whatever XML parser you're using, you can probably skip buffering the response and putting it in a StringBuffer, and instead pass your parser the response InputStream directly.

Answer (score 2):

No. You should use `new URL(url).openConnection()`, or some abstraction like [http components](http://hc.apache.org/) or a [rest-client](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/)